# How to pass parameters in url using google cloud functions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using http calls to call a cloud function.
I have a URL in the form
url: 'https://api.shipengine.com/v1/labels/rates/rateid,

Now I need to pass values dynamically in rated whenever the function call happens.
How to pass the value into that URL.
I am attaching my cloud function too.

```
exports.shipmentlabelwithreturnid = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

var request = require("request");


var rateid = req.body.RateId;
  console.log(rateid);

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.shipengine.com/v1/labels/rates/'+ rateid,
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'application/json',
     accept: 'application/json' 
   } 
 };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});

});
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code?

Comment: its showing unauthorised error

Comment: And how did you want us to help you if you are hiding what is the problem?

Comment: If you read the documentation, you will see that it requires api key in the header.

Comment: is this the correct way to pass a value?

Comment: probably it is. You can find the correct way in the documentation as well. Don't be lazy, and read it. I am not going to read it instead of you just because you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

You should use promises, in your Cloud Function, to handle asynchronous tasks. By default `request` does not return promises, so you need to use an interface wrapper for request, like [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise)  which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise", as follows:

```
....
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.shipmentlabelwithreturnid = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  var rateid = req.body.RateId;
  console.log(rateid);

  var options = { method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://api.shipengine.com/v1/labels/rates/'+ rateid,
     headers: 
        { 'content-type': 'application/json',
         accept: 'application/json' 
     } 
  };

  rp(options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Get response: ' + response.statusCode);
      res.send('Success');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // API call failed...
      res.status(500).send('Error': err);
    });

});
```

Also, it is important to note that you need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse n the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since https://api.shipengine.com is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.

---

On the fact that you have to use promises to handle asynchronous tasks, I suggest that you watch these videos from the Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=28s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk which explain this key concept.